# Cakephp multiple forms in single view

Tags: forms, cakephp

On my edit view I have created 2 forms :

```
<?php echo $this->Form->create('EditPasswordUserForm')); ?>
<?php echo $this->Form->create('EditInfoUserForm')); ?>
```

Hence, I created 2 Models  (2 files) :

```
class EditPasswordUserForm extends User
{
```

and

```
class EditInfoUserForm extends User
{
```

Controller User :

```
public function edit($slug)
{                   
    $this->loadModel('EditPasswordUserForm'); 
    $this->loadModel('EditInfoUserForm');
    $editpassword = $this->EditPasswordUserForm->findBySlug($slug);
    $editinfo = $this->EditInfoUserForm->findBySlug($slug);

    if(empty($this->data))
    {
        $this->request->data['EditPasswordUserForm'] = $editpassword['EditPasswordUserForm'];
        $this->request->data['EditInfoUserForm'] = $editinfo['EditInfoUserForm'];   
    }

}//end edit
```

I got this error message : 
Erreur: Class 'User' not found
Fichier: C:\xampp\htdocs\projectmvc\app\Model\EditPasswordUserForm.php

Could you please help me.

Thank you
Ligne: 4

Comment: where is the code of your user class?

Comment: I got it!
I just use the model 'User' in my edit function.
I think we should use it at the least one time.


Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just import `User` model in your extend models, like as

```
App::import('Model', 'User');
class EditPasswordUserForm extends User
{
    //
}
```

and

```
App::import('Model', 'User');
class EditInfoUserForm extends User
{
  //
}
```

For best documentation read [Behavior for Model Inheritance](http://bakery.cakephp.org/articles/santino83/2011/02/19/behavior_for_model_inheritance_the_missing_feature)

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to create two classes.

You can just do:

```
echo $this->Form->create('User', array('action' => 'editPw'));
echo $this->Form->create('User', array('action' => 'editInfo'));
```

In your UsersController:

```
class UsersController extends AppController {
     public function editPw() {...}
     public function editInfo() {...}
}
```